# Why do use @model in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, model

I'm getting my feet wet in ASP.NET 5 and developing the backend. The question is that assuming there is no direct relationship between Model and View in the MVC design pattern, why do we insert into View a code piece that contains such a term that conflicts with the said principle. Already we passed the data to be viewed to our View from Controller, so why do we need a statement as such?

Comment: The MVC pattern is not the same as the ASP.NET MVC framework. It becomes easier to understand when you abandon that notion.

Comment: I'm new, and I didn't use anything related to MVC other than Asp.net 5. I opted for it because it is the latest and unified version from here on out. And I learned MVC and this design doesn't fit the idea mentioned around.

Comment: You're right. The terminology doesn't line up. The Model in the ASP.NET MVC framework is not the same as the Model in the Model View Controller pattern.

Answer (score 1):

@model in asp.net core 5 tells asp.net core what type the object you passed into the view from the controller is.

say you have a model called User

```
public class User {

   public int Id {get; set;}

   public string Name {get; set;}

}
```

then your model in the .cshtml view you can do @model User

You can read more here on the asp.net core docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio